# How to use enum in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have used ENUM in a table of a MySQL database. How can I get all stuff where type = a, b, c?

Simply, if I use VARCHAR, then I can use:

```
SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE type IN ("a","b","c")
```

But using ENUM it does not work.

How can I get all stuff where type = a, b, c?

Note: Type is used as ENUM not CHAR or VARCHAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FIELD like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `stuff` WHERE FIELD(`type`, "a", "b", "c");
```

That should be the proper syntax to apply the logic from your question. It all boils down to weird type casting issues with the way ENUM lists work - Ideally the best way to go is setup forign key relation ship with a table that houses something like:

```
TypesTbl
+---------------+
| AK  |  Value  |
+---------------+
|  1  |    a    |
|  2  |    b    |
|  3  |    c    |
+---------------+
Stuff
+------------------+
| PK  | * |  type  |
+------------------+
|  1  |   |   1    |
|  2  |   |   2    |
|  3  |   |   1    |
|  4  |   |   3    |
+------------------+

SELECT s.* FROM `Stuff` AS s LEFT JOIN `TypesTbl` t ON s.type = t.AK WHERE t.Value IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

That way you use a left join (or whichever fashion) in your query and you don't have to update the DDL just to add a new ENUMerated value. The first part of the answer I believe supports what you're trying to do. The second part was just additional information.

Comment: @ marco sorry but it is really not worked for reference check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146173/are-this-is-bug-in-mysql-enum

Comment: You may wish to just edit this question rather than post a whole new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE type IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Comment: it is not my problem but when i run it all is found in result. i found all even if his type = d , e, f

Comment: Post the DDL for the stuff table then - this definitely works and filters appropriately for me...

Comment: I agree - what is the actual DDL for the table you're using?